# Angular resiseable element : mwlResizable resize-handle

Tags: css, angular

I'm using `mwlResizable` in Angular to change the size of div, but I need to change the size of the area where the resize cursor appearance in order to make it easier to resize, but I tried to add.

```c
.resize-handle-left,
      .resize-handle-right {
        position: absolute;
        height: 100%;
        cursor: col-resize;
        width: 5px;
      }
```

But nothing changed.